# Keep redux state on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have react-redux and react-router in my webapp and im trying to change the route while keeping the redux state. I tried all of these and they all removed the redux state:

```
props.history.push({ pathname: `/my-path`}); // did this using withRouter and useHistory
<Link to={'/my-path'} />cool link</Link>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I keep the state? (The reason I can't keep it in localStorage is because when the user closes that page, then the data should go away)

Answer (score 1):

Redux doesn't preserve the state once you refresh the website. If you want to persist data you should use localStorage, and use the event `window.onunload` to clean it once your browser or page is closed.

Check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rmacuna/7746709ff3ebd031cb28d573ef6a24e6)

Alternatively, you can pass data when you navigate programatically just like this

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

...

function myComponentA() {
  const history = useHistory()
  
  const navigate = () => {
    history.push('/pageB', {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Dan'
    color: 'Red'
    })
  }
  
  return <button onClick={navigate}>Go to page B</button>
}

...
```

In component B, use the hook useLocation() and then access the state property, and you should see your data right there.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

...

function myComponentB() {
  const location = useLocation()
  return <h1>{location.state.name}</h1>
}

...
```

What calls my attention is that if you are using react-router-dom, the link button should preserve the state in your redux store. The data is only cleaned once your browser reloads. Check [this sample](https://gist.github.com/rmacuna/fc292f3984019632c48987fe0466372a) using hooks and redux-toolkit, which could be the real solution for your problem. Once you navigate to the component B the state should persist.

For more documentation see

Redux Toolkit: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/
react-router-dom: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start